# ¿Cómo hacer un arreglo de NumPy de 0 y 1 en base a un arreglo de probabilidad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy

Sé que utilizando random.choices en Python puedo hacer esto:

```
import random


array_probabilities = [0.5 for _ in range(4)]
print(array_probabilities)  # [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

a = [random.choices([0, 1], weights=[1 - probability, probability])[0] for probability in array_probabilities]
print(a)  # [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo con NumPy?

Comment: no sé si entendí lo que querés hacer pero quizá te sirva : a=np.random.binomial(1,0.5,4) donde basicamente el primer valor es el rango, en este caso 0 y 1, el segundo valor es la probabilidad y el tercero la cantidad de casos y ya no necesitas todo lo anterior.

Comment: Creo que sí, es lo más cercano a lo que estaba buscando.

Answer (score 0):

No es en base a probabilidades, pero podrías usar [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#).

Así:

```
numpy.random.randint(0, 2, 4)
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://trinket.io/python3/f5810b242e).

Comment: Gracias, pero no me sirve. Necesito que se generen en base a las probabilidades. He visto que se puede algo similar con np.random.choice(), pero para ello necesito asignar probabilidades por valor y me salgo del rango.